# Meaning of the phrase "run hot" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [article](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-46072979).

> "Today's jobs report is a landmark in the long recovery since the Great Recession, showing the power of a tight labour market to raise pay for American workers if allowed to **run hot** for a sufficiently long time," said Andrew Chamberlain, chief economist at the job website Glassdoor.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "run hot" means to continue unabated, to continue without being reduced.

If measures are not taken to counter the tight labor market (such as admitting tens of thousands of foreign workers on H-1B visas) the result will be wage increases for US workers.

The underlying principle is supply-and-demand.  If the supply of labor(ers) is increased, the cost of labor goes down. If the demand for labor increases, but the supply does not, there is competition to get labor, with companies "outbidding" each other to attract talent. If you allow the latter condition to persist for long enough without abatement, wages rise.